# MacVim current tab goes black when closing another tab

Tags: macvim

I am currently having an issue with MacVim:

If two tabs are open say `tabA` and `tabB`. When I am on `tabA` and then close `tabB`, the `tabA` goes black and I need to refresh it. I do the refresh with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (select All) .

Any idea why that is happening and how I can fix it ?

Comment: 1) Could you provide more detail on what you mean by "The tabA goes black"

2) If you cycle through the tabs with `gt` and `gT` does the same issue show up?

Comment: How are you able to close other tabs from current tab?

Comment: Also do you reproduce the behavior when starting vim without your `.vimrc` (̀`vim -u NONE`)? (@SibiCoder see [the doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabclose): `:tabclose` accepts an argument)

Comment: You can probably refresh with Control-L which would at least save you from selecting everything, assuming it works. ;)

Comment: Same issue here. Any solution so far?